# Virtualmin outgoing email goes to spam folder

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, email-validation, virtualmin

I have VPS at Hostwinds and I host my company website on it. I have an issue with outgoing email. Every email send to clients goes in their spam folder. In the header details I see that email authentication is PASS, but still goes in the spam folder. What worries me is one line in the middle of the header: **Received: from mydomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])** . This is the email header:

```php
SPF:    PASS with IP 123.456.789.123 Learn more
DKIM:   'PASS' with domain mydomain.com Learn more
DMARC:  'PASS' Learn more

Delivered-To: myemail@gmail.com
Received: by 2002:a05:600c:2512:0:0:0:0 with SMTP id d18csp2849809wma;
        Sun, 30 Aug 2020 09:10:26 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-Smtp-Source: ABdhPJxJilweL27JR79vtPCAMzHED+3eOqm/43WBjywm9Kd1BZCpiPt5sizaAr5giUSayqvkRcbS
X-Received: by 2002:aca:724c:: with SMTP id p73mr1349454oic.123.1598803826168;
        Sun, 30 Aug 2020 09:10:26 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1598803826; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=qq545ttDSaZHhFNhUHVv9MCEmFQSQoM68j8HFF5xYbaqp1a4Vid+LN6myAkFMqY5IU
         9RRNQekRExzrHcegQ2cmaQ3NpR+b3+xeu/GakXnLzJGGvLx6zjgGWcI757gc3G/DEDs+
         CsmEB3J36wg91suAG6SKtfCexvuaQuOYO2fNbd1NysGtwsJjarnj5ilieh3ut6ReWu8N
         PzcMjaJ2zbQHXUkBxgM1AG03UhbSXlypmeQJOEXnems8pPL+ytVVFuDLTSY6h3AnQ5Sl
         770f+tjhFW01y++ftZp0n5MWNQAf9SNUxiYD/NRFT+1d523qLJulz2+md1bKCjRjBbBJ
         Z5PQ==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=content-transfer-encoding:message-id:user-agent:subject:to:from
         :date:mime-version:dkim-signature:dkim-filter;
        bh=/uVZaDgKu5ckl+oayfwbuWWkFIHwnJbHWiyokjkFpqY=;
        b=d5uFkvhfbgQ2TtnJLGmixBQafE5xQs73bQFh+BL403zno5b9qH77VavUQu+tp4spgA
         0tHMLoTvJOzhOrnrPKBoWkYxyThOtNCcCG2sN9uqPEK1lZbFRFrbKf7FqUsNDQQNODJd
         lQ7RAOVXS3zJjJle8el7sQuXw0CBTF8zM0TTQoPFJ7735YmtUkkBQwaZyhKi8HP0sBxn
         51I4FBrJtUHJWB1mBeidqChrhd26WtFtaKDVcrquSljdOZ8Zdi6CDhP0N8DVwSYX6kNg
         1fvJ1S/LPICGWm/wEnpkqWcp52egWbNYU94yGstuGUnsxGVCEyu5QyzoboLUfuGLPMEi
         mpbw==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com header.s=default header.b=qWoCXeE4;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of John@mydomain.com designates 123.456.789.123 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=John@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
Return-Path: <John@mydomain.com>
Received: from hwsrv-myserver.hostwindsdns.com (hwsrv-myserver.hostwindsdns.com. [123.456.789.123])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n9si3239879otq.34.2020.08.30.09.10.26
        for <myemail@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_3 cipher=TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 bits=256/256);
        Sun, 30 Aug 2020 09:10:26 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of John@mydomain.com designates 123.456.789.123 as permitted sender) client-ip=123.456.789.123;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.com header.s=default header.b=qWoCXeE4;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of John@mydomain.com designates 123.456.789.123 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=John@mydomain.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.com
Received: from mydomain.com (localhost [127.0.0.1]) by hwsrv-myserver.hostwindsdns.com (Postfix) with ESMTPA id C34505000C6D for <myemail@gmail.com>; Sun, 30 Aug 2020 16:10:25 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Filter: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 hwsrv-myserver.hostwindsdns.com C34505000C6D
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com; s=default; t=1598803825; bh=/uVZaDgKu5ckl+oayfwbuWWkFIHwnJbHWiyokjkFpqY=; h=Date:From:To:Subject:From; b=qWoCXeE4l55YNaNV6k/kr6ySb+dTmHNKlAa3lESHfvUEJ5g47cb8DaeF6uav2moaQ
     qrh8aHMKqNsWumx6R7poQ/jD3pTrTdZGRsxBdwdwE4P1qtexOrBLlRrxo9FRsMn8lD
     TE/U7mhJ6l1gkBv6pY/pqV+/yJoZaBOxl/4H7DK3I8MFannGYVfivz1uA6O78OSjKD
     kIacp+k3W7CV42l9yn6VwPFJmKqqdLlfitZ3esLFcw7ygzvXx37YeSL0ljEkcUh3CJ
     APEwG0gE/sQfo/VvF31urzNzHvkuU+yMQSitRXnVpkxrxHvbpwjv+07Z0CmSxkFmbI
     KOds89R71FL2Q==
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2020 11:10:25 -0500
From: "John-mydomain.com" <John@mydomain.com>
To: myemail@gmail.com
Subject: Test email again
User-Agent: Roundcube Webmail/1.4.8
Message-ID: <493106b566f97bb7a4e314e4334ce685@mydomain.com>
X-Sender: John@mydomain.com
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

My host file contains the following lines:

```php
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
123.456.789.123  hwsrv-myserver.hostwindsdns.com hwsrv-myserver
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It takes time to build IP reputation for an email server. I bet your email server new. use mx toolbox to see if your IP isn't blacklisted anywhere. Please ask your clients to mark your email as NOT SPAM. it will take some time, but it will go to the inbox eventually.